# How to change when html input field starts horizontal autoscroll?

Tags: html, css

I added `padding-right: 90px` to the `<input>` and now if the entered text exceeds the point at which it gets to the padding, the text starts to get cut off and the horizontal scrolling starts when the text has gotten to the end of the input fields width(minus the padding).
The text start being cut off at this point:[image: The text starts being cut off at this point]

And it does not start horizontally scrolling up until I add some more text that fully gets to the end of the `<input>` field(minus the padding). It does not start auto scrolling up until the letter H in the image below[image]

I would like it to start auto scrolling as soon as the text reaches the point of the `<input>` field where `padding-right: 90px` begins. I do not want it to cut off and start scrolling upon the addition of additional characters.

```
input[type=text], select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 11px 19px;
  margin: 7px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 90px;
}

<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="name">
```

Comment: do you want to always see the last part of the text if the text is long?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I want the input to just start scrolling as it would normally without any padding.